# Apache 2 does not load mod_deflate

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-deflate

I'm running Apache 2 on a Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.8 x86_64 standard box, and can't seem to get mod_deflate enabled.

This is a WHM installation, so I am making amendments to one of the include files that isn't changed by WHM automatically. I have verified that I'm editing the right file.

I've added the `LoadModule` directive in to the configuration file:

`LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so`

But I can't find it (checked with `apachectl -l`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `apachectl -M` instead to see a list of all loaded items.

Comment: cheers, question updated

Answer (score 0):

These are modules that are statically compiled into the apache executable, don't confuse them with modules that are loaded dynamically (at runtime).

Comment: See this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970151/how-to-check-mod-deflate-is-enabled-in-apache